# VS Express 2015 C#: picturebox width/height not in pixels?

Tags: c#, picturebox, pixel, units-of-measurement

If I create picturebox element on a form, the properties panel allows me to set the width/height to a value representing pixels.

However in code it seems a different unit size is used for measurement.

Example; i put the width at 128.

Both in the editor and in runtime the form will show a picturebox of 128 pixel width.

Now, If i try to read picturebox.width value in code it gives back 85.

If I try to change the width to 128 in code, it gives me an actual bigger box then 128 pixels.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Whoever upvoted the post or OP - please add what framework you are using (WnForms, WPF,...)

Comment: using System.Windows.Forms;
It's just a standard C# project in VS Express 2015.